# Why using SetAsPopup prevent event FrameLoadEnd to be executed using a CefSharp ChroniumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CEFSharp with WinForms C#, I added an handler on FrameLoadEnd of a ChroniumWebBrowser control.

I also created my own LifeSpanHandler to create a custom popup window. This is working great but I still have a problem with the FrameLoadEnd not executing when the ChroniumWebBrowser is set as a popup: ChroniumWebBrowser.SetAsPopup();

Can someone point me out what I have to do to fix this?

I already tried to remove the "SetAsPopop()", this fix the event but I can't use this solution because the website that I'm tring to "automate" will redirect me somewhere else if I don't call the SetAsPopup(); over my ChroniumWebBrowser popup.

To help you see my problem I made a small solution that demonstrate it. You can download it via this link :

http://www.blacketik.com/stackoverflow/FormTester.zip

The zipfile is big because I included everything needed to test it, including cefsharp/CEF. I made the solution using Visual Studio 2015.

To debug the solution, you will have to look at your console output.

Thank you

Comment: do you have actual code that you can post in regards to your issue please show us code..

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see details of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As it was difficult to show you the probleme without a complete solution, I uploaded one and provided a link to it.

You must use visual studio 2015 to open it (2013 may also work). 

Everything should work, if not you may have to reconfigure the cefsharp winforms package using nuget.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure you solution is going to be the best one, I've provided an answer that should get around your problem, sounds like your structuring of the popups maybe less than idea. Personally I won't download a `zip` from an unknown source. In future I'd consider creating a `Gist`, and just uploading the key files.  https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Another great question. Google got me here. Why oh why is it closed as off topic. I can only say thankfully people still reply and answer these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `ILoadHandler` and assign a new instance, e.g. `browser.LoadHandler = new CustomLoadHandler()`

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/ILoadHandler.cs

The `FrameLoad/End` events of `ChromiumWebBrowser` aren't called for `Popups`.

Comment: Thanks!!!! It was exactly what I was looking for!!!!!